# Служба работает в интерактивном режиме, а при запуске "Как служба" перестает получать информацию из сети

Tags: c#, windows-service

Сабж, у службы пробовал права и local system и network system ставить. Ноль эмоций. В интерактивном режиме инфу получает, когда запускаю как службу - запускается и работает, но инфу из сети не получает.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался?
Возможно это из-за стороннего драйвера (используется открытие сервера из dll).

Comment: А какая именно процедура отрабатывает не так?

Comment: Данные строки, когда запущена как  служба. Program.PriceChecker.DataEvent += new IPriceCheckerEvents_DataEventEventHandler(pcc_DataEvent);
            Program.PriceChecker.OpenServer();

Comment: Ну, и какая строка работает не так? `PriceChecker` ведь не библиотечный класс.

Comment: библиотечный. В том то и проблема. Когда запускаю интерактивно (https://coding.abel.nu/2012/05/debugging-a-windows-service-project/) всё отрабатывает как надо, когда служба - тупо стоит и ничего не делает.

Comment: Не может быть библиотечный. Дайте ссылку на MSDN.

Comment: тьфу. Я видимо не правильно понял слово "Библиотечный" сразу подумал про dll. Извините, в общем нет возможности в него заглянуть

Comment: Окей, тогда проблема, по-видимому, в нём. Если это сторонняя компонента, спросите у разработчика, в чём дело.

Comment: Можно, конечно, декомпилировать при помощи какого-нибудь рефлектора, и разобраться. Но хотите ли вы с этим возиться? Мне было бы лень, например.

Comment: Значит в настройках службы или где-то ещё не может быть проблемы?

Comment: Ну, я не знаю, что есть PriceChecker у вас. Проблема наверняка у него внутри. (Вы, кстати, так и не сказали, что это такое.)

Comment: драйвер для устройства, которое стучится в TCP порт. К нему документация сводится к банальному перечислению функций. Опен порт открывает TCP порт в который будут прилетать строка с прайсчекера. Это не тайна, я просто не знаю, как вам объяснить что это)

Answer (score 1):

Дай бог красноречия объяснить эту несусветную чушь))

В общем, в настройках драйвера можно менять tcp порт, тобишь он куда-то это записывает и видимо под пользователя, поэтому запускается интерактивный режим и берет правильный порт и прайс чекер достукивается до приложения, а когда запускается от службы, то порт берется по стандартной настройке(не тот, что указан для пользователя) и прайс чекеры стучаться не в тот порт.

Выход - поставил все устройства на стандартный порт.
Второй выход - поставить настройки для того же пользователя( в ту же ветку реестра) от которой запускается служба.